# How to stop Pepper Robot talking in the middle of sentence

Tags: pepper

I want to show slideshow and pepper would read on it.

```
u: (say) I am pepper $slide=1 I can do this and that $slide=2 i have many functions $slide3=1 like this and that
```

And i want to cancel it when i hold Pepper head sensor for 1 second.

How is this possible?
I will show slideshow and i want user to be able to stop it in the middle of if user touches robot's head.

Answer (score 2):

You can do two things :

1. **Stop the say of ALTextToSpeech** : you can cancel the function *ALTextToSpeech.say("phrase")* with *ALTextToSpeech.stopAll()* . [ALTextToSpeech doc](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/naoqi/audio/altexttospeech-api.html#altexttospeech-api)
2. **Stop by deactivate your topic** : your pepper say a topic dialog and you can stop it by deactivating the topic with *ALDialog.deactivateTopic("name_topic")*. [ALDialog doc](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/naoqi/audio/dialog/aldialog-api.html?highlight=dialog#ALDialogProxy)

for example, your topic is like this :

`topic: ~ExampleDialog()
language: enu
u: (say) I am pepper $slide=1 I can do this and that $slide=2 i have many functions $slide3=1 like this and that`

When the user touches the robot's head, you call the function `ALDialog.deactivateTopic(ExampleDialog)` and that cancels it.